# Use match in replace

Tags: javascript, regex, string, str-replace

I need to put every non-alphabetic character between spaces.
I want to do this using RegExp, and I understand it enouch to select them all (`/(^a-zA-Z )/g`).
Is there a way to use the original match inside the replace?
(something like)
`str.replace(/(^a-zA-Z )/g,/ \m /);`
If not I will just loop over all of them, but I really want to know it it is possible.

Comment: [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: Yes, I know its from the prototype, but that doesnt help me to reuse the string....

Comment: But it would help if you would follow the link ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can give the `String.prototype.replace()` function a RegExp as it's search. You can also give it a function to handle replacing.

The function will give you the match as the first parameter, and you return what you want to change it to.

```js
const original = 'a1b2c';
const replaced = original.replace(/([^a-z])/gi, match => ` ${match} `);
console.log(replaced);
```

If you just need to do something simple, you can also just use the `$n` values (`$1`, `$2`, etc) to replace based on the selected group (the sets of parentheses).

```js
const original = 'a1b2c';
const replaced = original.replace(/([^a-z])/gi, ' $1 ');
console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: The groups are counted from 1? (Meaning $1 is is always it when there is only one group?)

Comment: Yes, they are 1-indexed, as opposed to the usual 0-index for things like array. So `$1` is always the first. That's actually a near-universal convention of regular expressions, regardless of language.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can use regex with group:

```js
var text = '2apples!?%$';
var nextText = text.replace(/([^a-zA-Z])/g, ' $1 ');

console.log(nextText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check replace function on this link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace